# I'm trying to do dynamic dropdown but it seems that ajax is not working/running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a dynamic dropdown with my form with Philippine locations, it goes like this choose city -> then barangay data will show up depends on what city you chose.

I have a problem with running ajax, it seems like the moment it reaches `$ajax` it stops there.

I've already tried `alert (city)` before `if (city)` and within `if (city)` and it works, the alert shows.
I tried putting `alert(city)` or `alert(error)` within `ajax` but nothing showed up, so I concluded that ajax is not running at all (unless my syntax is wrong)

```
<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s6">
    <select name="barangay"  id="barangay">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a Barangay</option>
    </select>
    <label for="barangay">Barangay</label>
    <?php echo form_error('barangay');  //------------------------------------------------?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a City</option>
          <?php
          foreach ($cities as $city)
          {
            echo '<option value="'.$city->city.'">'.$city->city.'</option>';
          }
          ?>
        </select>
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <?php echo form_error('city');  //--------------------------------------------------?>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Populate data to state dropdown */
    $('#city').on('change',function(){
        var city = $(this).val();
        //alert(city);
        if(city){
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'index.php/createPatient/getphilippineLocations',
                data:'country_id='+city,
                success:function(data){
                    $('#barangay').html('<option value="">Select State</option>');
                    var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    if(dataObj){
                        $(dataObj).each(function(){
                            var option = $('<option />');
                            option.attr('value', this.name).text(this.name);           
                            $('#barangay').append(option);
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('#barangay').html('<option value="">State not available</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#barangay').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

```
//this is the function it is suppose to call
public function getphilippineLocations()
{
    $states = array();
    $country_id = $this->input->post('country_id');
    if($country_id)
    {
        $states = $this->createPatient_model->getAllBarangays($country_id);
    }
    echo json_encode($states);
}
```

```
function getAllBarangays($city)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ph_locations WHERE city = '".$city."' ORDER BY name ASC";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Sadly there is no error message, I can't tell if ajax is running but it suppose to show all the barangays for that city once the city is chosen by the dropdown(an administrative division in the Philippines, similar to village or district)

Comment: Did you check if there is some error in the console.

Comment: There's an error here `<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  jquery is not loaded

Comment: It doesn't "just stop there", it has to do *something*.  Time to make further use of the browser's debugging tools.  Is there anything at all on the development console?  In the browser debugger's network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Add an `error` callback to the `$.ajax()` operation.  Place a breakpoint in both callback's in the browser's debugger.  Which one is invoked?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile whoops just notice that

Comment: Does it work after?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Sadly no, still nothing shows up in Barangay

Comment: Ok let me prepare answer for u

Comment: @RynxHynx have you thought about changing `var option = $('<option />');` to `var option = $('<option>');`

Comment: @Panciz I notice there is an error 'failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)' on the URL in javascript it seems

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile just tried it still nothing happens

Comment: @RynxHynx: Do you know what a 404 error is?  Hint: It has *nothing* to do with your JavaScript code.

Comment: That 404 means your controller is not found

Comment: @David yeah I just fix it,  the error not is showing up anymore

Comment: What does the preview of the network console shows any data?

Comment: @RynxHynx: Then what *is* happening?  How is this failing?  Now would be an ideal time to continue to explore your browser's debugging tools.  What is the HTTP request being made?  What is the server's response?  When you place debugging breakpoints in your callback functions, which one is invoked?  What happens when you step through it in the browser's debugger?  You need to provide information about the problem.  Note also that nothing in the question has been updated for the changes you're making.  The question still shows a simple typographical error in your `<script>` element.

Comment: try to run getphilippineLocations function manually and pass city(or country_id) . check if your are getting any response or not.

Answer (score -4):

Hope below will be helpful for you.. try once and let us know if it won't work

```
  <select name="barangay"  id="barangay">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a Barangay</option>
  </select>
```

var UrlCities = url To Get Cities,
    BindDropDownValues(UrlBindBenefitPlans, 'barangay', 'ID', 'Name', true, selectedValueInEditMode);

```
function  BindDropDownValues(url, controlToBind, dataValueField, dataTextField, isSelectRequired, valueToSelect) {

    var ajax = $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        global: globalAjax,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null && data != undefined && data.length > 0) {
                $("#" + controlToBind).empty();
                if (isSelectRequired == true) {
                    $("#" + controlToBind).append($("<option title=\"-Select-\"></option>").val(0).html("--Select--"));
                }

                for (var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < data.length; itemIndex++) {
                    var singleObj = data[itemIndex];
                    $("#" + controlToBind).append($("<option></option>").val(singleObj[dataValueField]).html(singleObj[dataTextField]));
                }
                if (valueToSelect != undefined && valueToSelect != "") {
                    $("#" + controlToBind).val(valueToSelect);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return ajax;
};

</script>
```